# npm run and kill background porcess synchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, mocha.js

Currently I'm setting up some integration/api test's for my nodejs express application. The routes I'm testing does require a connection to AWS-DynamoDB for some CRUD operations on the tables.

Now for the purpose of not messing around with my current table data, I have decided to run the tests on a local db. AWS offers a way to run [DynamoDB locally](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html). After installing (extracting) the tar/zip to the correct location, I just have to run a command which does start a local server on port 8000.

command:

> java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
>   -sharedDb -inMemory

Now I want to preapare a script in my package.json file to do the following tasks.

1. start the local db by the given command
2. wait some seconds so the server is setup and ready (timeout 2 seconds)
3. run the tests (which also does create the necessary tables with entries)
4. shut down the local db (kill the process of "1.")

My attempt looks like the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test:int": "npm run db:setup && npm run test:int:run && npm run db:kill",
    "test:int:run": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/integration/**.spec.js",
    "db:setup": "java -Djava.library.path=~/opt/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ~/opt/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -inMemory",
    "db:kill" : "dont know what to do here"
   }
```

My Problems here:

- Now I dont know exactly how to run the processes synchronously including the timeout of 2 seconds so the local db is ready to handle the requests.
- I also need a way to consistently shut down the local db at the end ("4." / "db:kill")